# How to make dynamic response with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to listen socket into bash to produce dynamic response. I tried do like this ``` nc -l 8088 -c``echo 'Request got, let's produce it' ``` but -c option is deprecated and unsupported now.
Then I tried to list port using /dev/tcp: `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088;
cat <&3` But i've got an error:

```
connect: Connection denied* 
line 1: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088: Connection denied*
line 2: 3: Wrong file descriptor*
```

- Translated from russian word for word

Answer (score 1):

That syntax, according to the Bash manpage, is for opening a connection to an existing socket. I don't know of an option to create a socket using only Bash. And your nc command uses port 8000 not 8088.

[update]
OK then, but you're also missing the -p switch to set the port. Didn't catch that before.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ nc -l -p8088 -c 'echo bleah' &
[1] 4752
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088; cat <&3
bleah
```

For an example of using pipes, see the bottom of this page, in the explanation of a proxy: http://www.stearns.org/doc/nc-intro.v0.9.html, hopefully you can adapt it for your needs.

Why not use inetd? The main problem with using netcat with Bash is that there's no straightforward way that I can think of to send back a reply, because you don't know what port they used to connect with. Whereas inetd handles the tcp/ip connection for you, letting your shell script just deal with stdin and stdout.

Comment: Ports mismatch fixed. That's two variants of one functionality: listen tcp ports and make dynamic responces

Comment: nc -l -p 8088, you left out the -p

Comment: -c option is not available with my netcat version. maybe you know how to process request with a pipe?

Comment: So using piping i've got stuck again. I'm doing this `nc -l 8080 0<pipe | echo -ne "HELLO\r\n"  1>pipe` and everything is ok, but when i do this `nc -l 8080 0<pipe | while read line; do if [ "X$line" == "GET /  HTTP/1.1" ]; then echo -ne "/" 1>pipe; fi; done >pipe;` nothing gonna happen.

Comment: see update; still not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish or what limitations (with regard to tools) you're placing on yourself.